# How to make 'adb shell' to read /etc/profile or other configuration files?

Tags: bash, busybox, ash, adb

I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.10.24), and it uses `ash` from `busybox` as `/bin/sh`. The system support login from serial console and `adb shell` from PC.

Now I found the `shell` started from serial console did read the environments defined in `/etc/profile`, but the `shell` started by `adb shell` does NOT.

For example, the `/etc/profile` is as follows,

```
# cat /etc/profile
export PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin"

if [ "$PS1" ]; then
        if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
                export PS1='# '
        else
                export PS1='$ '
        fi
fi
```

in serial console,

```
# echo $HOME
/root
# echo $ENV

# echo $PATH
/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

But in `adb shell`,

```
/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget # echo $PATH
/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget # echo $HOME
/
```

The shell started by `adb shell` is launched by `adbd` in target Linux, so is there a way to make the shell started by `adb shell` to read `/etc/profile` or other configuration files for its environments?

Answer (score 0):

You could try use a wrapper script for achieve what you are asking for:

```
adb shell 'ENV=/etc/profile sh -i'
```

A simple alias for this could be:

```
alias adbshellenv="adb shell 'ENV=/etc/profile sh -i'"
```

Comment: So where should I put the wrapper script, in Linux where the adbd is running?

Answer (score 0):

With lots of studies and tests, I think I found one way to solve my request/answer.

Firstly, change the source codes of `adbd` to call a wrapper script of `/etc/init.d/adbshell_wrapper.sh` in target Linux.
The wrapper script calls at least 2 things, as follows,

```
#!/bin/sh
/etc/profile
/bin/sh
```

With this solution, the `adb shell` can get the same environments as what `login` gets in serial console.

Answer (score 0):

From the beginning of the `INVOCATION` chapter of `man bash`:

> A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a `-`, or one started with the `--login` option.

So just change `adbd` to set the `argv[0]` of the shell it's starting to e.g. `-bash`.

Comment: If the system is using `ash` not `bash`, shall I use `-ash`? If so, I will try that and update my result here.

Comment: Yes. Although you could technically set it to any value that includes `-` as the first character, using the name of the shell that's being invoked is the expected behavior.

Comment: I am not sure if I really got your point.  I changed the source code of `adbd` to launch `shell` as `/bin/sh -ash`, is it correct or not? I got following result, `PS C:\Users\test> adb shell
- exec '/bin/sh --login' failed: No such file or directory (2) -`